# how to get data from message.properties in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am trying to send a message to user like his browser language setting but
always it sending a message through by default **`messages.properties`** rather than **`**messages_es.properties`****

```
${g.message(code: 'default.welcomenote.message')}
```

OR

```
<g:message code="default.welcomenote.message" />
```

i set my browser language as spanish

Comment: Is the file called `message_es.properties` or `messages_es.properties` (with an "s")?  The default Grails properties file is called `messages.properties` so if you want to override messages in that file with translated versions then the translated files should have the same base name.

Comment: its my mistake to wrote.. actualy.. file name is messages.properties... i get the value from messages.properties

Comment: is something we need to change in resource.grrovy file to set locale language

Comment: If you want to change the default locale to Spanish you can add this line to your `resources.groovy`: `beans = { localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) { Locale.setDefault(new Locale('es', 'ES')) } }`

Comment: no.. i don't want as default.. i just want..if browser language set as spanish then message should be send from messages_es.properties otherwise by default through messages.properties..